# Challenge: Bitmap Centroid

Tags: algorithm, bitmap, collision-detection, centroid

I'd like to calculate the centroid of a bitmap (black and white) stored as a bit-packed array of integers. I know there are fast algorithms for counting the number of set bits in an integer, but this doesn't help me calculate a centroid. Any ideas?

As an example, if my bitmap looks like this:

```
111000
111000
111000
000000
000000
000000
```

The centroid is at 1, 1. Packed into 32 bit integers (you choose the Endian), it might look like this: {width: 6, height: 6} { 3817734144, 0 }.

Bonus points if you can also get the mass (9 in the example) without iterating over each bit.

Comment: I don't think it matters for the algorithm, but for the record: do you want floating-point accuracy, or are integer coordinates sufficient? If so, how should they be rounded?

Comment: What guarantees about connectedness do you offer?

Comment: the mass should be pretty trivial via one of the aforementioned set-bit-counting algorithms. probably simplest to just do it as a separate pass. as for the centroid, my gut feeling is that your data representation is really working against you, as far as any efficient algorithm goes, because your packing it into integers is trading off space saving for a boost in time complexity for anything that cares about the geometric layout of the bits.

Comment: @AakashM None, unfortunately.

Comment: @Martin I had that feeling too, but I have to both render geometric figures against this bitmap and query it quickly for single points. The actual render process isn't the bottleneck though, so if you can advise a better representation I'd be interested.

Comment: if space isn't a problem, just round the width up to the nearest byte and represent it as an array (i.e. pad each row so that you're byte-aligned; e.g. the array would be 6x8 in the example you cited). calculating the centroid would be a lot easier, then.

Comment: 8x increase in space, but I don't know how that helps you on a 32+bit architecture?

Comment: it lets you iterate over the rows quickly and easily. alternatively if you want to save some space, you could pack as many as would fit into an int, but not let a row span two ints.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you're going to process this a row at a time. (Once you've got the total mass, and center of mass of each row, it's a weighted average to get the x and y coordinates of the centroid).

So in other words you've got a row of bits b<sub>i</sub> and you want to calculate the sum of b<sub>i</sub>f(i) for some functions f. If f(i)=1, that's the bit count (let's call that C), and if f(i)=i, it'll give the total *moment* of the mass M (which you'll divide by C to get the center of mass).

For inputs less than 8 bits, you can easily store tables for C and M, each 256 bytes wide. Let's write numbers bigger than 8 bits as h:l, where l is the lower 8 bits of the number, and h is the rest of the bits.

Then

```
C(h:l) = C(h:0) + C(0:l) = C(h) + C(l)
M(h:l) = M(h:0) + M(0:l) = M(h) + 8C(h) + M(l)
```

the only tricky bit being the 8C(h), corresponding to those C(h) bits being shifted down 8 places when we calculated M(h) instead of M(h:0).

Non-recursively, if your input as *bytes* is x0, x1, x2, x3...

```
C(x) = C(x0) + C(x1) +   C(x2) +   C(x3) + ...
M(x) = M(x0) + M(x1) +   M(x2) +   M(x3) + ...
             +8C(x1) + 16C(x2) + 24C(x3) + ...
```

and then you can pass M and C to average over all lines.